# Fast Poisson solver (with Dirichlet BC zero) on a *truncated* Cartesian 3D grid

Tags: numerics, poisson

I find myself in the position of having to solve

$-\Delta u = f$ on a *subset* of Cartesian grid points that don't necessarily form a cuboid domain subject to a homogenious Dirichlet boundary condition ($u = 0$). The Laplacian filter I require is the standard 7-point stencil for 3D.

Now, for a cuboid domain, I know this can be efficiently solved using a type-I discrete sine transform (DST) since the DST diagonalizes the equation system.

I wonder, whether it's possible to leverage the fast DST for domains that are *not* cuboid. It's still a Cartesian grid, but only a subset which is not necessarily convex and might include holes.

Are there fast algorithms that can exploit the Cartesian grid structure? Or do I have to use a more general solver (like an algebraic multigrid preconditioned conjugate gradient method or something like this)?

Maybe there is an efficient method to reduce my problem to another with an emcompassing cuboid domain so I still get to use the DST? As far as I can tell, I could introduce source terms in $f$ on my actual boundary so that the DST-based approach will reconstruct a boundary of zero. But the problem with this is that determining those source terms seems to require solving a big and "ugly" linear equation system (dense matrix which is not trivially diagonalizable).

What would be your recommended solver for this problem? The number of unknowns are in the tens of millions.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, no; you can't use the DST
approach for a case with general geometry or boundary
conditions.

The best way to understand this is to consider WHY the
DST approach works for the "rectangular" case. For
this case, we happen to know that the complete set
of eigenvectors of the differential equation are
products of sin functions. We can then conveniently
express the solution as a sum of the eigenvectors.
The DST is a fast way to compute the eigenvectors
in this case.

For a general geometry, the eigenvectors are not simple sin functions
and we have no cheap way to compute them; that makes
an eigenvector basis unattractive.

Since you say your grid is Cartesian, it seems like algebraic multigrid
would be an attractive option and is theoretically faster than using FFT.
As shown on page 2 of these [notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/ma221_Spr16/Lectures/Multigrid_Ma221_2016_2pp.pdf) by Demmel, FFT has performance
proportional to $N log N$ while multigrid is order $N$, where $N$ is the
number of equations.

Comment: I'm aware of why the DST works for the cuboid case. However, I don't think you can easily invert such a statement (inverse error fallacy). The DST would still be applicable if you found an efficient way to turn problem A (on a non-cuboid domain) into problem B (with cuboid domain). I actually already did something like this where this problem reduction step is very cheap. But my feeling is that for this current problem (with homogenious Dirichlet BC), that "problem reduction step" would be too costly and not worth the hassle.

Comment: Yes, I want to solve a linear equation system that you would get by using the 7-point stencil (common for finite difference discretization). But the interesting bit is that this is not an "approximation" to my original problem. It's *exactly* what I want to solve. :)

Comment: "tens of millions" should give you an idea of the size of the problem which is surely going to inform the choice of the solver, isn't it?

Comment: What would be your recommendation for an efficient solver?

Comment: My question about problem size was actually about WHY such a fine grid is required? You say this grid gives the "exact" solution to your problem. Why is an approximate solution from a coarser grid unacceptable? If you simply MUST solve this system of equations, since you have a regular grid, why don't you use standard multigrid?

Comment: I'm exploring different possibilities to solve a large, (linearly) constrained, non-linear least squares problem. I would use a gradient-based iterative solver for this. One approach to satisfy the linear constraint is to project the cost function's gradient to the desirable linear subspace so that the gradient-based iterative solver is not tempted to step out of that linear subspace. This projection turns out to be similar to the projection method used for incompressible flow simulations which is no surprize because what I'm trying to solve for is a discretized divergence-free velocity field.

Comment: Now, since this projection would have to be applied in every iteration of the "outer" cost function minimizer, I'm obviously interested in the fastest approach to solve such a linear equation system. I didn't say I don't want to use any multigrid solver. I'm just asking for recommendations. Is a geometric multigrid solver the fastest way to handle such a problem? If so, can you recommend any existing implementations? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If a more general Poisson solver turns out to be much slower than an FFT-based one, I would try to figure out a different way to satisfy the constraint. The other two options are (a) explicit parametrization and (b) penalization of constraint violations. Every approach has their pros and cons. And for the purpose of this question I'm just trying to figure out what the best/fastest way to solve the linear equation system is. That linear equation system turns out to be a discretized Poisson problem with the standard 7-point Laplacian kernel with a homogenious Dirichlet boundary condition.

Comment: Its kind of difficult to find Poisson solver benchmarks. I didn't have much luck. Sure, the geometric multigrid approach seems to be the most promising answer for this question. But how does it compare to an FFT-based one on a cube for the problem size I hinted at? Is it the same? Does it take 1000x the time? If it's so much more costly, I would try to avoid having to solve such an equation system.

Comment: @sellibitze The geometric multigrid is faster than FFT, if done right. If the size of your problem is "tens of millions", then you probably also want to parallelize the thing. Which is the point where things start to get messy again, at least if you prefer OpenMP/Cuda/OpenCL parallelization over MPI parallelization.